# Failed to create JVM in windows 7

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded adt bundle from developer site and ,now I cannot open the eclipse properly in windows 7 32 bit.It shows the error "Java virtual machine cannot be loaded".I searched a lot in google and changed my eclipse .ini file still i face the same problem this is my eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
-vm
c:\path\to\32\bit\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.0.v20100503
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Please help me thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Change this line to your folder on disk where JDK/bin/javaw.exe is located.

```
c:\path\to\32\bit\bin\javaw.exe
```

For example on my pc its this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: Which path you used? Copy paste it here.